# jquery change cursor on hover and click

Tags: jquery, css, hover, cursor, toggle

I'm using an image zoomer and I need 2 different mouse states on hover.

**#1** On hover of the containing `<div>` the cursor becomes a 'plus' symbol.
 **#2** When the user clicks the cursor changes to a 'minus' symbol. (now zoomed in)
 **#loop** Once clicked again the cursor goes back to the plus symbol (default hover-view)

I can't use mousedown/up or `:active` because I need it to stay until clicked again,
so I think using `toggle` is my best bet.

So far I've got this http://jsfiddle.net/fCe9B/ but it doesn't work quite right.
Depending on where the default hover image-call is placed, either the `toggle` won't replace the `hover` or vice versa.
As long as I can get both cursor states to appear I should be good.
Can anyone help me solve this?

**CSS**

```
.cursor {cursor:move;}
#box {height:300px;width:300px;background:blue;}
#box:hover {cursor:help;}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#box").click(function(){
$("#box").toggleClass("cursor");
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this where you check if the images has a certain css class that changes the cursor.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".box").hover(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("zoomed")){
          $(this).removeClass("zoomed");
        }else{
          $(this).addClass("zoomed");
      } 
    });
  $(".box").click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("zoomed")){
        $(this).removeClass("zoomed");
      }else{
          $(this).addClass("zoomed");

      }
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.box {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:blue;
    cursor:w-resize;
}


.zoomed{
    cursor:crosshair;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Heres the jsfiddle so you can try it.
http://jsfiddle.net/fCe9B/9/

Comment: That is close, but it is cycling through 3 different cursors, I only need 2 :-)

Comment: Oh, if you want just 2 states change the hover event to crosshair and you are done! http://jsfiddle.net/fCe9B/4/

Comment: This works great but it won't work for me. I believe I need to use `toggle` so it will remember which state the cursor was in if I hover off the image and back on again. Clicking zooms the image in/out, and on mouseout the image stays in the zoomed state it was in. Thus if: (hover > click > mouseout > hover) the cursor state will be wrong. This code would work if it wouldn't reset on mouse out.

Comment: You actually have the state of the cursor on the clicked var. Asking before changing the cursor on the hover event would keep the old state of the image. Like this . http://jsfiddle.net/fCe9B/5/

Comment: That is working! However with multiple occurrences of the `<div>` it will use the mouse-state of the last `<div>`. Could I use `document.getElementById("#Id")` to add the class to each div?  

I've modified the JS/html/css a bit in here but I think it would work. http://jsfiddle.net/fCe9B/6/

Comment: Instead of using the class box you can use the id. $("#box").click()

Comment: But then I would have to hard code every ID. Would `document.getElementById("#Id")` work here? I've created #box1 and #box2:
  
http://jsfiddle.net/fCe9B/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40586/discussion-between-rmbl21-and-ghost-echo)

Answer (score 0):

The cursor you can use can be the crosshair one or you could use a custom image that you have in this case a plus symbol:)

```
.cursor {
cursor : url(image/cursor.jpeg);
cursor : crosshair;

}
```

then you can just say

```
on click .cursor { 
cursor : url(image/cursor.jpeg);
}
```